# How to filter in django

Tags: python, django

I want to filter Consultants(this is my model from where I want to filter)
 on the basis of username.
But when I try to filter it returns a empty list.

my code is

```
username=request.user.username
print "value of  requested logged in user is",username
user=Consultants.objects.filter(username='username')
print user.consul_id
```

When I print consul_id it says `QuerySet` object has no attribute `consul_id`.

How can I filter? Should I use **get** to filter.I have used get but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: do you have an object with `username='username'` inside the `consultants` table?

Comment: I believe you mean't `username=username` where the first one is a kwarg and the second is a variable defined somewhere up in your code. Mind the ""

Answer (score 3):

You should change this:

```
user=Consultants.objects.filter(username='username')
print user.consul_id
```

to

```
user=Consultants.objects.filter(username='username').first()
print user.consul_id if user else 'None'
```

Because calling [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) returns a Queryset. You need to get the first element from that queryset(hence use `first()`). Also you can use [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) method